# window.open external link opening in new tab

Tags: javascript

So I have a confirmation dialog box that opens when button is clicked, but window.open in javascript opens it in new tab. I tried lot of things like _self, _top but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can open this in same tab/page.

Here is the code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="sample"></a>

JAVASCRIPT

 $('.sample').on("click", function (e)
    {
        var link = this;
        e.preventDefault();

        $( "#ConfirmDialog" ).dialog(
        {
            resizable: false,
            width: 300,
            buttons:
            {
                "Yes": function()
                {
                     window.open($(link).attr("href"));
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function()
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `_blank` should work.

Comment: No you can't, you need a modal for that. Otherwise, you'll always open a new tab/window.

Comment: Set `window.location = $(link).attr("href")`

Comment: window.location does work, thanks!

Comment: You have a missing " in the href, I hope that is not the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the current page's url, simply set `window.location` to the new url

```
$('.sample').on("click", function (e) {
    ....
            "Yes": function() {
                window.location = $(link).attr("href")     
            },
    ....
});
```

I have answered in the comments, but since this is what you are looking for, I'm adding it as an answer too.